# scala type alias to java enum does not work?

Tags: scala

Scala type alias to java class works fine, i.e.

```
type JavaDate = org.joda.time.LocalDate

val date = new JavaDate(2019, 6, 20)
println(date)
```

But type alias to java enum does not work?

```
val m1 = java.time.Month.JANUARY
println(m1)

type JavaMonth = java.time.Month

val m2 = JavaMonth.FEBRUARY
println(m2)
```

Error: not found: value JavaMonth: val m2 = JavaMonth.FEBRUARY

How can I use alias to java enum? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [import renaming](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html#Imports) instead of type aliases like so:

```
import java.time.{Month => JavaMonth}
val m2 = JavaMonth.FEBRUARY
```

Type alias might be more appropriate for simplifying more complex types like

```
type Response = Future[Either[Error, Int]]
```